# How can I force casting object when getting result of HTTP Request

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm making a HTTP Request to an external API that respond:

```
{
id: 1,
user_id: 1,
name: "Fake Tournoi",
slug: "fake-tournoi",
dateIni: "2018-06-13 00:00:00",
dateFin: "2018-06-14 00:00:00",
registerDateLimit: "2018-06-10 00:00:00",
sport: 1,
promoter: "promoter2",
host_organization: "host2",
technical_assistance: "tech2",
rule_id: 1,
type: 0,
venue_id: 1,
level_id: 7,
created_at: "2018-06-02 18:56:44",
updated_at: "2018-06-12 10:55:46",
deleted_at: null,
championships: [
  {...},
  {...},
  {...},
  {...}
  ]
}
```

So, here the main object is a `Tournament` and then championships is an array of `Championship` objects

I thought I was casting objects when getting data with:

```
getTournamentWithTrees(): Tournament {
    this.loading = true;
    this.treeService.getTournamentWithTrees(this.slug)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(tournament => {
        this.tournament = tournament;
        this.loading = false;
      }, err => {
        this.loading = false;
      });
    return null;
  }
```

this method is supposed to have a `Tournament` type, and then in `Tournament`definition, I have:

```
export class Tournament {
  id: number;
  ...
  competitors: Competitor[];
}
```

Thing is when I try to use methods on `Tournament` object or with `Championship` objects with:

```
<div *ngIf="championship.hasPreliminary()">
    has Prelim
</div>
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _v.parent.context.$implicit.hasPreliminary is not a function
```

I guess it is because my Championship data is not considered as Championship
 object. How should I do to solve this ?

Comment: What the signature of `getTournamentWithTrees` ?

Comment: it returns a Tournament, but I should refactor it so it gives me an Observable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a constructor like this :

```js
export class Tournament {
  constructor(payload: Object) {
    Object.assign(this, payload);
  }
}
```

And call it like this :

```js
this.http.get('...')
  .map(tournaments => tournaments
    .map(tournament => new Tournament(tournament))
  );
```

When you make an HTTP request, your payloads aren't typed : giving a class to your HTTP call only enables the autocompletion of your IDE.

Comment: will it work for sub objects like Championships ? I could do it the same way in Championship constructor, but they are never instanciated, so it wouldn't work in that case, would it ?

Comment: You're right. This should be recursive. I personally use [Class Transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) for that, but you can implement it yourself if you want to.

Comment: I  used the Class Transformer you mention, and it works great ! Please include it in the answer!